# Index position of sortable while still being dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I would like to know where a sortable is in a list before it is dropped.

Once the the item is selected by the user, it is removed from the DOM.  When I listen for the `change` event, all the item are there except for the selected item.

`$( "#sortable" ).sortable('toArray')`

As the user moves the selected item over the other elements, I would like to know the **proposed** area where the user is about to drop the object.  I want to do this so that I can give more feedback to the user before they commit to dropping it.

Is there a way to get the index of a sortable before it is actually dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by finding the index of the placeholder element in the `change` event, we do want to make sure we ignore the li element that is currently being dragged. I do this by simply adding a class, you could also use `$.data()`. If you do not ignore the li element that is currently being dragged you will double count since there is a placeholder and the original element in the ul at the time of `change`.

Code is below and here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yYKmw/16/

### HTML

```
<ul  id="sortable">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<div id="output">
    <span></span>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#sortable { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin: 1em; 
    padding: 0; 
    width: 30%; 
    float: left;
}
#sortable li { 
    height: 20px; 
    background-color: khaki;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 2px;
}
.sortable-placeholder {
    background-color: red !important;
}
#output {
    clear:both; 
    border: thin solid black; 
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    color: black;
}
```

### JS

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    start: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.addClass( 'ignore' )
    },
    change: function(event, ui){
        var elements = $('#sortable li').not('.ignore')
          , placeholderElement = elements.filter( '.sortable-placeholder' )
          , index = elements.index( placeholderElement );

        $('#output span').html('Current index: ' + index)
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.removeClass( 'ignore' );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/6G9rY/2/

> ```
>  $(function() {
>      $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
>   });
>   $('#draggable').mousemove(function(){
>         var html = ["The clicked div has the following styles:"];
>         var styleProps = $("#draggable").css( ["top", "left", "right", "bottom"] );
>         $.each( styleProps, function( prop, value ) {
>         html.push( prop + ": " + value );
>         });
>         $( "#data" ).html( html.join( "<br>" ) );       
>   });
> ```